# Limit of the ratio of the areas of complex surfaces.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, area

Let $D$ be the disc in the complex plane centred at the point $\frac{\pi}{4}$  and of radius $r$. Let $D'$ be the
image of this disk under the map $z\to \sin z$. Evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\text{Area}(D')}{\text{Area}(D)}.$$

My attempt: The given disc is $|z-\frac{\pi}{4}|\leq r$, i.e., $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+re^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. We note that when $r\to 0$, $\sin z\to \sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ How to think forward?

Comment: The expression $\left|z-\frac\pi4\right|=r$ defines a circle, not a disk.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of a differentiable function $\psi:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, if you fix a point $p\in\Bbb{R}^2$, and take discs $B_r(p)$ (I use $B$ instead of $D$ because there's already lots of $D$'s from the derivatives) centered at $p$, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\text{area}(\psi[B_{r}(p)])}{\text{area}(B_r(p))}=|\det D\psi_p|
\end{align}
After all, if you look at your multivariable calculus change of variables formula then the absolute value of the determinant gives precisely the  “infinitesimal ratio of areas” (in fact this formula holds even for differentiable functions $\psi:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$).

For complex functions $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$, the derivative $f'(p)=a+ib$ can be represented as a matrix:
\begin{align}
[Df_p]=
\begin{pmatrix}
a&-b\\
b&a
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which has determinant $a^2+b^2$, which also equals $|f'(p)|^2$. Therefore…

Comment: Can you recommend a book where I can get this thing : absolute value of the determinant gives precisely the “infinitesimal ratio of areas”  . @peek-a-boo